# Build a closed source Android library based on Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library

I would like built a closed source android library using the Gradle. My library has some dependencies to open source projects. How should I structure my library? Can I use gradle?

Comment: if you manage to resolve this please share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I use gradle?

**Short answer:**

Yes.

**Long answer:**

I would assume that your library is packaged as `aar` (contains resources and compiled bytecode).

First thing you need to know is that at the moment of writing this post there is no way to create fat-aar libraries, which means that you'll have to distribute dependencies of your library separately. The most convenient way to do that, in my opinion, is to generate `pom.xml` file and publish your library on Maven repository (`maven` plugin can do all of that), so clients will just fetch all dependencies themselves. Since it is a "private" library, that could be your company's closed repo by access rights (in simple words - create special user for your repo and share password with interested parties).

One downside here is that all dependencies will be exposed in `pom.xml` and you won't be able to obfuscate them. Personally, I don't think that this is an issue.

Moreover, you get the huge advantage of being able to deploy build automatically and let clients use snapshot versions of the library. This is extremely helpful when you're trying to fix issues and want to deliver them to users fast. On client's side, all they need to do is either just update version in their `build.gradle` or just re-sync project in case if they were using snapshot.

Second thing. Since your library is closed source, you need to run proguard to obfuscate everything but public interface of your library (all public methods which are exposed to end user).

Remember, that even after obfuscation your code still can be decompiled and all string literals are still there. So, although it was said million times already, avoid storing any critical data in the library (such as passwords, keys, etc.). It is not as hard to extract it as you might think it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X28Oogg2Q3k

Third thing. I highly suggest you to create internal test project (as a gradle submodule) which will use your library, so you will be sure that you're not making any breaking changes.

Hopefully this answer made things at least a bit easier for you.